# Ogre3D RetrieveVertexData for Linux

Tags: ogre3d

I have a problem loading meshes in the Ogre3D framework with the
'getMeshInformation' function from http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/RetrieveVertexData
when compiled on Ubuntu.
The program crashes due to a segmentation fault.

It is said that it has problems on AMD64 Linux,
but there is no mention of a version that works on that system
or what has to be changed in order for it to work.
The program runs fine on Windows when compiled with VisualStudio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Working code here:

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Raycasting+to+the+polygon+level#Adapted_version

It was kinda hidden though.